# How to change the "Return" button in IOS keyboard to "Next" button in using JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I'm working on HTML application and Let us suppose that I'm running my application in IOS devices like IPAD.I have many text boxes in my application,when I click on a text box to enter a text...keypad appears.In that Keypad there will be "Return" button,I want to change that "Return" button to "Next" button using JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT,so that when I tap on that "NEXT" button the cursor should go to next field in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way changing the text from return text to Next on your Keyboard using **JavaScript** or **jQuery**. However, it does allow the user to navigate between textFields through a keyboard input view with arrow keys. That's the only way. See below:

[image]

**Note:** One thing is that if you place your `<input .../>` tag inside a `<form>` tag, it changes from return to Go (though it may not serve your purpose, just wanted to let you know).

Comment: Not only the text need to be changed from "Return" to "Next" but the functionality of "Next" button need to be implemented.Even though arrow keys are present(next and previous),"Next" is required in place of "Return".

Comment: @Raju that won't be possible in cross-platform or web applications.. This can only be done on native apps.